# How to specify ssh key with pdsh

Tags: ssh, cluster

I'm using pdsh, but can't find any documentation or examples of specify the ssh key. Usually, I do `ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pem <address>`. How do I change the pdsh command `pdsh -R ssh -w ^server.txt "date"` so I can specify my ssh key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdsh) suggests an environment variable:

```
PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND="-i $HOME/.ssh/mykey.pem"
```

You need to either `export` the variable (to make it available 
to `pdsh`'s child processes) or define the variable and run 
the command in one go:

```
# Either:
export PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND="-i $HOME/.ssh/mykey.pem"
pdsh -w^server.txt date

# Or
PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND="-i $HOME/.ssh/mykey.pem" pdsh -w^server.txt date
```

<sup>I don't know why you gave `-R ssh`; for me it perfectly works without.</sup>

See also [*"pdsh can't find identity file, but ssh can. why?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35809382/5830574) on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).
The poster has a different problem (quoting) but uses the same approach.

Comment: Just tried and it didnt work :/

Comment: @Soubriquet Updated. Please try again.

Comment: I keep on getting `Permission denied (publickey)`. I'm using a list of hosts names formatted with one host on each line e.g. `192.168.0.10`. However, I also tried with `ubuntu@192.168.0.10`. Neither worked.

Comment: `Permission denied (publickey).` is a different error. It means you didn't distribute the corresponding _public_ key to the remote hosts. Did you?

Comment: Nvm works. I forgot to add thr PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND to my .bashrc